how to show persistant notification in flutter, as when someone calling you while your app is in the backround/terminat state notification shown
i want to show persistant notification in flutter, as when someone calling you while your app is in the backround/terminat state notification shown, unless the user accept or reject it, want to achieve this functionality how can i acheive this.
i tried this but not working
notifications.show(20,
            title,
          description,
            const NotificationDetails(
                android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  "20",
                  "App",
                  importance: Importance.max,
                  priority: Priority.high,
                  autoCancel: false,
                  ongoing: true,
                  visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
                  category: AndroidNotificationCategory.alarm,
                  fullScreenIntent: true,
                  audioAttributesUsage:
                      AudioAttributesUsage.voiceCommunicationSignalling,
                  actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
                    AndroidNotificationAction('accept_action', 'Accept'),
                    AndroidNotificationAction('reject_action', 'Reject'),
                  ],
                ),
                iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
                  presentAlert: true,
                  presentSound: true,
                  presentBadge: true,
                )),
          );

